# Trouble casting integers to doubles

Tags: java, casting, integer, double

I'm trying to get this program to call function arrayAvg with an array of {1,2} and return a double of the average (which would be 1.5).

This is what my code looks like at the moment. Anybody have an idea where I'm going wrong? :X

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main
{
    public static double arrayAvg(int[] array){

        int total = 0;
        int count = 1;
        double average = 0.0;

        for(int item : array){
            total=total+item;count=count+1;
        }
        double dTotal = (double)total;
        double dCount = (double)count;
        average = (dTotal/dCount);
        return average;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){

        int[] input = {1,2};
        double result = arrayAvg(input);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

Comment: You fail to mention what is wrong.

Comment: How do you know you are doing anything wrong? At a glance, I don't see anything wrong with your code. Does it compile and run? If not, what happens when you compile it? What happens when you run it?

Comment: @Code-Guru: With such formatting it is indeed difficult to spot subtle issues ;p

Comment: Thanks for telling us what output you expect to get. It would be nice if you also told us what output you actually get.

Answer (score 2):

Initialize **count as 0 not as 1**.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic for determining `count` is wrong. It should start at 0 not 1.

Also, you could simply just get the array length.

Comment: i have no clue how i managed to overlook that, thank you!!

Comment: @HeinrichArnold: Your code formatting is horrible, and makes the code very difficult to read ;) Try using your IDE's formatting function.

Answer (score 1):

Why you need count ? you need basically number of values in the array to divide it with.
Simply use arry.length, this would return you the number of elements in the array and use it for division

```
int len = array.length;
double dTotal = (double) total;
double dCount = (double) len;
average = (dTotal / dCount);
return average;
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a problem in your logic,
you have initialized

```
int count = 1;
```

which is wrong,
you should initialize that variable with 0 as below

```
int count = 0;
```

The below is changed code

```
public class Main {
    public static double arrayAvg(int[] array) {
        int total = 0;
        int count = 0;
        double average = 0.0;
        for (int item : array) {
            total = total + item;
            count = count + 1;
        }
        double dTotal = (double) total;
        double dCount = (double) count;
        average = (dTotal / dCount);
        return average;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] input = { 1, 2 };
        double result = arrayAvg(input);
        System.out.println(result);
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1.5
```